# Proving chances using C#

Tags: c#

I'm mathematically not very strong and I'm trying to prove that 1 in 100 chance means that on average you are likely to win 1 item in 100 tries.

I'm trying to prove this using 1 million runs, the average should be around 100, I believe if I did 1 million runs.

However, the way I'm getting the average is not correct.

```
Random random = new Random();

// Lets assume droprate is 1 to 100
var dropRate = 100;

// Lets set tries to 1 million
var tries = 1000000;

List<int> wins = new List<int>();

// + 1 at end because this functions counts from 0 to 99
var prize = random.Next(0, dropRate) + 1;

// lets do 1 million runs
for (var i = 1; i <= tries; i++)
{
    // Lets create a random number 1 to 100
    var randomNumber = random.Next(0, dropRate) + 1;

    // Lets compare this random number with prize to see if it's equal.
    if (randomNumber == prize)
    {
        // Lets add the number of the current run to the list so we can later check average
        wins.Add(i);
    }
}

var wonRewardOnAverageRuns = wins.Average();

// Lets see what the average is of all wins
Console.WriteLine($"You won the prize in average of {wins.Average()} runs.");
```

Comment: You should increment a counter in your `if` body instead of adding to a list. Or, with your approach, your computed chance would be `wins.Length / (float) tries`.

Comment: Why would the average be 100? Are you saying that out of 1,000,000 tries you'd expect to win 100 times? That isn't equivalent to 1 in 100. I might be misinterpreting your question though.

Comment: `wins.Add(i)` adds which trial (1 to 1000000) to your wins, you should only add one for each win. If you win on the millionth trial you only won once, not a million times.

Comment: 1/100 = 0.01 and 100/1000000 = 0.0001. Not sure I follow the logic in the question (without having read the actual code anyway).

Comment: I did `Console.WriteLine($"You won the prize in average of {wins.Count / (float) tries * 10000} runs.");` and this keep giving number around 100. And I'm not even sure why this is the case.

Comment: @OS - It's dividing the number of items in `wins` by `tries * 10000` (10,000,000,000). Although I don't see why you're doing that multiplication.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb because without multiplication I get a number in decimals. I think `Wins / Tries * 10000` gives the correct answer, sometimes its `99` and sometimes `100`.

Comment: @OS - If you're just trying to get from a decimal representation to a whole percent, you just need to multiply by 100, not 10000. Then you'll be getting 0.99 and 1 a lot, which is close/equal to your target of 1% wins.

Comment: For what it's worth, System.Random isn't the best random number generator. Don't use it as the basis of a high-stakes lottery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 1 in 100 chance of winning means that if you did something 1 million times you'd expect to win roughly 10,000 times. The code below demonstrates this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sequence = RandomSequence(1_000_000, 100);
    var groups = sequence.GroupBy(i => i).OrderBy(group => group.Key);

    foreach(var group in groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", group.Key, group.Count());
    }
}

static IEnumerable<int> RandomSequence(int numberofItems, int upperBound)
{
    var random = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < numberofItems; i++)
    {
        var value = random.Next(upperBound);
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

If you run this and look at the output you'll see that each each number was picked roughly 10,000 times. Sometimes it more, sometimes it less. The variability is down to the randomness of what we're doing and the quality of the random number generator.